# Scroll View me desordena los elementos

Tags: java, android-studio, scroll-view

estoy empezando a programar en android studio y tengo problemas a la hora de usar el scrollview. he mirado tutoriales y la verdad no entiendo que esta pasando. por algún motivo que aun desconozco cuando uso el scroll view me desordena los elementos que intento ponerle. les dejo unas imágenes de como queda el layout y de como debería quedar además del código que tengo en el xml:

[image: sin scroll view (así debería quedar)]

y asi es como queda con el scroll view:

[image: con scroll view (no tendria que quedar asi)]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity2">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El `ScrollView` es un contenedor que, como indica su nombre, te permite hacer scroll cuando se exedan sus dimensiones asignadas, por lo que no genera problema en tu diseño.

Los `LinearLayout` sirven para presentar los objetos hijos tanto en filas `android:orientation="vertical"` como en columnas `android:orientation="horizontal"` dependiendo de tus necesidades.

También te permiten ir controlando a manera de cuadricula los espacios entre los hijos con la propiedad `android:layout_weight` de cada hijo, tratando de hacer lo más dinamico posible tu diseño en los diversos tamaños de pantalla que puedes toparte.

En tu caso, como necesitas que los elementos hijos de tu pantalla se muestren como columnas (una a lado de la otra) con cambiar la propiedad de

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

se resolvería tu problema, el detalle es que si agregas otro hijo dentro de ese `LinearLayout` te lo presentaría como otra columna.

Aquí depende de lo que busques con tu diseño. Normalmente se aconseja que los altos de los `LinearLayout` sean limitados a su contenido `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` para que no te oculten los demas objetos que quieras agregar.

Repito, **depende de lo que busques en tu diseño**, pero puedes tener un `LinearLayout` padre con orientación vertical que controle tus filas y un `LinearLayout` hijo con orientación horizontal que controle tus columnas de cada fila.

Como ejemplo de tu caso, algo asi:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
                    tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/avatars" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="48dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="84dp"
                    android:text="TextView"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hola. gracias por responder. Solucionaste mis problemas y me ayudaste a entender como funciona ScrollView de una vez por todas. Mil gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando un `constraintlayout` te recomiendo utilizar un `LinearLayout` para evitar problemas de posición de vistas, el código seria algo como esto:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical" >

      //TODO TU CONTENIDO GRAFICO AQUI

      </LinearLayout>
   </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```